# VS2019 compiler misinterprets UTF8 without BOM file as ANSI

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I used to compile my C++ wxWidgets-3.1.1 application (Win10x64) with VS2015 Express. I wanted to upgrade my IDE to VS2019 community, which seemed to work quite well.
My project files are partly from older projects, so their encoding differs (Windows-1252, UTF-8 without BOM, ANSI).

With VS2015 I was able to compile and give out messages (hardcoded in my .cpp files), which displayed unicode characters correctly.
The same app compiled with VS2019 community shows for example the german word "übergabe" as "Ã¼bergabe" which is uninterpreted UTF8.

Saving the .cpp file, which contains the unicode, explicitly as UTF8 WITH BOM solves this issue. But I don't want run through all files in all projects. Can I change the expected input from a "without BOM" file to UTF-8 to get the same behaviour that VS2015 had?

**[EDIT]**
It seems there is no such option. As I said before, converting all .cpp/.h files to UTF-8-BOM is a solution.
Thus, so far the only suitable way is to loop through the directory, rewrite the files in UTF-8 while prepending the BOM.

Using C++ wxWidgets, this is (part of) my attempt to automate the process:

```
//Read in the file, convert its content to UTF8 if necessary
wxFileInputStream fis(fileFullPath);
wxFile file(fileFullPath);
size_t dataSize = file.Length();
void* data = malloc(dataSize);
if (!fis.ReadAll(data, dataSize))
{
    wxString sErr;
    sErr << "Couldn't read file: " << fileFullPath;
    wxLogError(sErr);
}
else
{
    wxString sData((char*)data, dataSize);
    wxString sUTF8Data;
    if (wxEmptyString == wxString::FromUTF8(sData))
    {
        sUTF8Data = sData.ToUTF8();
    }
    else
    {
        sUTF8Data = sData;
    }
    wxFFileOutputStream out(fileFullPath);

    wxBOM bomType = wxConvAuto::DetectBOM(sUTF8Data, sUTF8Data.size());
    if (wxBOM_UTF8 != bomType)
    {
        if (wxBOM_None == bomType)
        {
            unsigned char utf8bom[] = { 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF };
            out.Write((char*)utf8bom, sizeof(utf8bom));
        }
        else
        {
            wxLogError("File already contains a different BOM: " + fileFullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this can not convert all encodings, basically afaik it can only convert ANSI files or add the BOM to UTF-8 files without BOM. For all other encodings, I open the project in VS2019, select the file and go (freely translated into english, names might differ):
-> File -> XXX.cpp save as... -> Use the little arrow in the "Save" button -> Save with encoding... -> Replace? Yes! -> "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"
(Don't take "UTF-8 without signature" which is also Codepage 65001, though!)

Comment: What will you do when VS interprets your ANSI files as Utf-8?

Comment: *"run through all files in all projects"* seems like a reasonable thing to do. Otherwise things will get even more messy.

Comment: My VS2019 doesn't do that. If I save übergabe  in a UF8 w/o BOM text file, it opens it correctly. Are you sure its not a compiler/options issue?

Comment: Due to such reasons, I write my C++ files with ASCIIs only in any case. If I intend to use UTF-8 in string constants for code points >= 128, I use octal sequences for UTF-8 encoding. E.g. `"ü"` can be written as `"\303\274"`. Hence, I'm not relying on whether the compiler reads ASCII, ANSI, or UTF-8 - it will work always.

Comment: Why auto detection is never going to work: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223

Comment: Just do what VTT suggested with an editor that can batch convert the encoding of multiple files.

Comment: Try turning off auto-detection: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> then uncheck "Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature."

Comment: @ Simon Mourier: I don't think I could be sure of that. Actually I asked this question to hopefully get an option/setting, that makes vs2019 read utf8 w/o bom correctly like yours does.
@ Adrian: That makes unfortunately no difference.
@ EveryoneElse:  Changing the encoding of each file with a script is my backup idea. But this could easily add new errors: Adding a BOM when there already was one, beeing unable to read the format, since each file could have a different encoding...
I was really hoping for some sort of "legacy mode", that made VS2019 read my files like VS2015 could.

Comment: @user3334630: "*The same app compiled with VS2019 community shows for example the german word "übergabe" as "Ã¼bergabe" which is uninterpreted UTF8.*" How does it show that word? Are you printing it in a console? Because that's a matter of how the console interprets the text. Try printing it to a file and loading it with a file reader that you can set to read UTF-8.

Comment: @NicolBolas The c++ framework wxWidgets, that I work with, offers me a message box (wxMessageBox) which resembles a standard message box with an "OK" button as we know it from windows apps. I use that message box and I need my text to (also) be readable from that box. Of course, if I write that text to a .txt file and open it with eg. notepad++, I could switch the encoding to "utf-8" and it would be displayed alright. But that is not my issue.

Comment: @user3334630: "*if I write that text to a .txt file and open it with eg. notepad++, I could switch the encoding to "utf-8" and it would be displayed alright.*" If that's the case, then your text is *properly encoded* in UTF-8; Visual Studio did its job correctly. So your problem is being able to give a UTF-8 string to wxWidgets and having it absorb it correctly. So that's an entirely different problem. Which would require wxWidgets expertise to solve, as well as an example of some code to use to do so.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think this is an missunderstanding. I wrote the text in question with VS2015 and saved it. Because of the unicode characters in that text, VS2015 saved that file as UTF-8 without BOM. Now, migrating to VS2019, UTF-8 without BOM is interpreted as ANSI, not as UTF-8. The result is text example I provided. So yes, the text is UTF-8 alright. All I was asking is VS2019 reading its own project files like VS2015 could. But dont worry about this anymore, because as suggested by other commentors, I translated all my files to UTF-8-BOM (see my EDIT) which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The option /utf-8 specifies both the source character set and the execution character set as UTF-8.

[Check the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019)

[The C++ team blog that explains the charset problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/)